# Which features would be interesting for a mathematician in a fractal program?

Tags: algorithms, applications, fractals

Many years ago I wrote this fractal generator:
http://uberto.fractovia.org/

It was shareware but then I put it as open source.
It's written in Delphi, a language that I don't use anymore. So I'm playing lately with the idea of rewriting on some other lang (scala maybe?).

On the mathematical part I'm not expert at all, so I don't know if there is something a mathematician would find interesting. Maybe none because of software like Mathematica. I really don't know.

For the graphic oriented people I implemented some algos for continuous coloring, including the ones listed here:

[Continuous coloring of a Mandelbrot fractal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/continuous-coloring-of-a-mandelbrot-fractal)

but I'd like to add some new ones.

Comment: Subjectively, implementing different ways of coloring a fractal (check the refs for these, I don't remember them all now) would be nice. Certainly, being able to zoom in any region should be implemented.

Comment: my program can do much more than that. It also has several fractal, showing the julia set of any mandelset point, showing escape orbits etc.

Comment: Oh, I remember using Fractal Forge when I was in college. Any plans to re-write it in a more portable language so it also compiles/runs on *nix?

Comment: An interesting feature would be to do batch generation on different zoom levels, so the output can be more easily stitched into an MJPEG or something.

Comment: That is runs on *nix, and can export to a vector format, of course.

Comment: If you end up supporting [DjVu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DjVu) as an export format, I'd be very amused...

Comment: The avi generation is already there. Be able to run on *nix and using a more general format are of course on top of the list (I'm not using windows since ages). Not sure about DjVu -> why?
About vector format -> considering that a fractal is a map of values I see no way to natively generate a vector image.

Comment: special functions support would be nice.

Comment: If I were that mathematician in a fractal program, I'd be looking for a way out.

Answer (score 1):

You might look to Mandelbrot's own work, a lot of which has to do with boundaries, also the relations of similar shapes on different scales and fractal dimension.

Comment: Can you post me a link or the name of a book?

Comment: @Uberto, probably [The Fractal Geometry of Nature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fractal_Geometry_of_Nature)

Answer (score 1):

For inspiration, try [Xaos](http://wmi.math.u-szeged.hu/xaos/) and the books [The Beauty of Fractals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beauty_of_Fractals) and *The Science of Fractal Images*.